# Significance of Dwaja Sthambha (flag post) at temples

Tags: temple

At the front of most temples we see tall flag posts (Dwaja Sthambha).

What is the significance of these structures? Why do some temples/deities have this while some don't?

Comment: Hayaśirṣapañcarātra, Agnipurāṇa & Viṣṇudharmottarapurāṇa states the dhvajā is to be hoisted in order to ward off misfortune. North Indian temples hoist the dhvajā on the temple rooftop while South Indian temples construct the dhvajāstambha instead without hoisting the banner. Agnipurāṇa describes a special rite regarding consecration of both dhvajā & dhvajāstambha. Viṣṇudharmottarapurāṇa states that shrines dedicated to Viṣṇu should have Garuṛa in the dhvajā, trident for Shiva, lion  for Devi, axe for Gaṇeśa & lion seated on crescent moon for Surya.